# wordpress - specific menus for specific page

Tags: wordpress, menu

Can I specify different menus for different page in wordpress??

Say I have pages A, B, C , D and I have menus menu1, menu2. I want page A, B to load menu1 and C, D to load menu2.

Is it possible?? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in many ways,

**using page id**

```
if(is_page(array('1','2'))) { 

wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu1' ));

} else { 

wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu2' ));
}
```

**Using special page template**.

If you have special [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)(page-id or page-slug) for page A and B ,Then you can call

```
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu1' ));
```

for other pages

you can use in page.php

```
 wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu1' ));
```

Using Widget also you can do this

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to allow a user to choose the nav menu location when adding/editing a page.

**Use a meta box with a dropdown** (select) with all the available locations, and then save the selected location in a custom field:

```
/**
 * Register the meta box.
 */
function wpse_183868_page_nav_menu_meta_box_register() {
    add_meta_box(
        'wpse_183868_page_nav_menu',
        'Nav Menu',
        'wpse_183869_page_nav_menu_meta_box',
        'page',
        'side'
    );
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse_183868_page_nav_menu_meta_box_register' );

/**
 * Display the meta box.
 */
function wpse_183869_page_nav_menu_meta_box( $post ) {
    $selected = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_page_nav_menu', true );
    wp_nonce_field( 'save', 'page_nav_menu_nonce' );
    ?>

<select name="page_nav_menu">
    <?php foreach ( get_registered_nav_menus() as $name => $label ) : ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $name ?>"<?php selected( $name, $selected ) ?>><?php echo $label ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>

<?php
}

/**
 * Save the meta box data.
 */
function wpse_183869_page_nav_menu_save( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['page_nav_menu'], $_POST['page_nav_menu_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['page_nav_menu_nonce'], 'save' ) )
        return;

    $nav_menus = get_registered_nav_menus();
    $nav_menu = $_POST['page_nav_menu'];

    if ( isset( $nav_menus[ $nav_menu ] ) ) // Paranoid - check the submitted value is definitely valid
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_page_nav_menu', $nav_menu );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_183869_page_nav_menu_save' );
```

Now in your template you can just use:

```
if ( ! $page_nav_menu = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_page_nav_menu', true ) )
    $page_nav_menu = 'default_location';

wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => $page_nav_menu ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Menu Swapper](http://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-swapper/) plugin for doing same thing using admin user interface.
Here is the [Demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAd0_RKvvLw) of this plugin.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12049419)

Comment: I agree with @milap  but that link is of wordpress plugin which is suitable for  this answer. I don't think wordpress will change that url or even you will do same.

Comment: What I mean is, you can't post link as an answer,  you always can post comment on question. As per so terms.